# Angular ag-grid filtering on enter key event

Tags: angular, filtering, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, angular13

I am using Angular ag-grid for filtering data. I have used floating filter on grid header.
Upon typing on filter as i type characters it automatically filter out the the result.
My requirement is i want grid to wait and filter once i press Enter key only.
How can i disable this auto filter and make it filter on Enter key event.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do one thing use input tag which will be your searchbox input then add one function on your input action in which you will apply check for keyboard enter key event code and if it matches then carryout your filtering else it will not filter till you press enter key. So, we can use Angular Hostlistner for capturing keyboard events & key codes.

Please let me know if this works for you.

```
<input (keyup) = "searchOptions()" type="text" matInput> //html code

//First import Hostlistner to read keyboard events in your TS file 
//Create one function to perform your searching & filtering

searchOptions(){ //Function will be called on keyup
  if(keycode == 0 (..respective keycode of enter key say as 0)){
  //Your logic to perform further action
 }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yes, added related explanation/code. Thanks, for reviewing